# HIVE: How to only select distinct values from two columns in two tables that does not exist in a third table?

Tags: join, select, hive, hiveql

I have three tables.

```
t1
Name | Version | ...
A        1 
A        2
B        1
B        3

t2
Name  | Version | ...
 A        1
 A        3
 B        2
 B        3

 t3 
 Name  | Version | ...
  A         1
  A         2
```

I want to select the distinct name and version values from table 1 and 2 that does not exist in table 3.

My current SELECT query selects the distinct values from table 1 and table 2 by

```
SELECT c.name,c.version FROM 
   (SELECT name,version from t1 
    UNION   
    SELECT name,version from t2
    ) c
```

This returns

```
 result
 Name  | Version
  A        1
  A        2 
  A        3
  B        1
  B        2
  B        3
```

What I want instead

```
wanted result
Name | Version
  A      3
  B      1
  B      2
  B      3
```

How do I correctly modify the HQL query to get this result? Thanks for any help given.

Answer (score 0):

Use LEFT JOIN with t3 table + filter not joined rows only:

```
SELECT c.name,c.version 
  FROM 
   (SELECT name,version from t1 
    UNION   
    SELECT name,version from t2
    ) c
  LEFT JOIN t3 on c.name=t3.name and c.version=t3.version
WHERE t3.name is NULL --do not exist in t3 table
;
```

One more possible way to do the same is using NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT c.name,c.version 
  FROM 
   (SELECT name,version from t1 
    UNION   
    SELECT name,version from t2
    ) c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM t3 WHERE c.name=t3.name and c.version=t3.version)
;
```

Comment: I read up a bit on some HIVE syntax, is this the same as using LEFT SEMI JOIN?

Comment: @kspr Hive support LEFT SEMI JOIN only if you do not need to reference left table columns, it efficiently works as IN/EXISTS. But in your case you need NOT EXISTS, this is why LEFT JOIN + filter is used. LEFT SEMI JOIN does the opposite to what you asked

Comment: @kspr Added one more option using NOT EXISTS

Answer (score 0):

you can use <> in join condition

```
 SELECT c.name,c.version 
  FROM 
   (SELECT name,version from t1 
    UNION   
    SELECT name,version from t2
    ) c
  INNER JOIN t3 on c.name<>t3.name and c.version<>t3.version
```